# asp:hyperlink not rendering correct HTML on server

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm working on a project that is in ASP.NET WebForms on .NET 2.0 and am running into a problem I can't seem to find a cause for. I have the following code in my aspx file:

```
 <table>
            <tr>
                <td>

                    <asp:HyperLink ID="supportLink" runat="server">Customer Support Docket</asp:HyperLink>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="entitlementsLink" runat="server">Edit Entitlements</asp:HyperLink>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

And when I run locally in debug mode, it works great. The links appear and the HTML is rendered properly as such:

***Local Rendered HTML***

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>

            <a id="ctl00_ContentMain_supportLink" href="ViewCustomer.aspx?customerid=659">Customer Support Docket</a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <a id="ctl00_ContentMain_entitlementsLink" href="EditEntitlements.aspx?customerid=659">Edit Entitlements</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, when I run it on my server in production, I get the following HTML generated:

***Server Rendered HTML***

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td>

                <a id="ctl00_ContentMain_supportLink">Customer Support Docket</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <a id="ctl00_ContentMain_entitlementsLink">Edit Entitlements</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

As you can see, the href is missing from both. In my code behind I am adding the URLs since I was having a hard time getting them to render properly in the aspx file:

***Code Behind File***

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        supportLink.NavigateUrl = string.Format("ViewCustomer.aspx?customerid={0}",
                                                Request.QueryString["customerid"]);
        entitlementsLink.NavigateUrl = string.Format("EditEntitlements.aspx?customerid={0}",
                                                     Request.QueryString["customerid"]);
    }
```

At this point I'm not sure what I can do. My plan was to re-write this site in the next few weeks in MVC4 but seeing as this is an internal site and not generating money it is low on my priorities list and won't get much more attention for awhile, which means I need to fix this issue.

The server environment is IIS 6 on Windows Server 2003 and the HTML renders this way in both IE9 as well as Chrome 24.0.1312.57. I have cleared the cache in both browsers to no avail and I know that the page is getting updated after a publish because other features that I added with the same change are actually working in production.

***EDIT***

[Rezalas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14903824/509746) was wondering where I got the customerid from. It is from the query string. To show that a blank query string wouldn't cause this here is the local and production HTML with no query string:

***Local Rendered With No Query String***

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>

            <a id="ctl00_ContentMain_supportLink" href="ViewCustomer.aspx?customerid=">Customer Support Docket</a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <a id="ctl00_ContentMain_entitlementsLink" href="EditEntitlements.aspx?customerid=">Edit Entitlements</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

***Production HTML With No Query String***

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>

            <a id="ctl00_ContentMain_supportLink">Customer Support Docket</a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <a id="ctl00_ContentMain_entitlementsLink">Edit Entitlements</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just making sure... you made sure you deployed the rebuilt .dll correct?

Comment: @RandomWebGuy I'm publishing directly from Visual Studio 2008. The dll is being pushed out there as changes in the same file are evident (new javascript functions are in there as well as new behavior).

Comment: server side changes? markup changes? both?

Answer (score 1):

For clarification, where is the customerid value coming from? Are you certain that the value when ran on the server is being properly pulled? I say this because it looks as though the ID isn't being provided, and as such the string isn't being built and the navigate url is being excluded because it doesn't have a value.

Comment: The customerid is from the query string which is seen on my code behind. I can copy page url with query string from localhost (where it works) to the prod site and it still doesn't work. The query string is definitely there in my testing.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the query string contains a value or not. The navigate URL for supportLink for example would just be ViewCustomer.aspx?customerid=

Comment: if you change the code to the following, does it work (on the server I mean)?

        supportLink.NavigateUrl = "./sometest.htm";

Comment: @Rezalas ok so this is weird. I changed the supportLink to a static url and then published and that showed up. Then I changed it back and published and it started working as normal. Not sure why. It must not have published the code behind.

Comment: @RandomWebGuy I guess. It is weird because there was other code in the code behind that was new and worked yet that didn't. Thank you for your help.